# How to include many images with a for-loop?

Tags: graphics, loops, for-loop

I would like to add many images to my document. The images are located in a folder named `./assets/images/` and are numbered as follows `0.png, 1.png, ..., 100.png`. How can I include them using a for-loop in Latex?

At the moment I do the following, which is not very aesthetic:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{./assets/images/1.png}
    \includegraphics{./assets/images/2.png}
    \includegraphics{./assets/images/3.png}
    \includegraphics{./assets/images/4.png}
    % and so on
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    for image in images:
        \includegraphics{./assets/images/ + image}
    \caption{}
    \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pgffor` package provides a very simple interface for loops like this.  I've made a helper command to change the number of images as you need; this is useful if you're using the same technique multiple times in your document, but you could just as easily hardcode the top value.

Assuming your images are named as in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\setnumimages}[1]{\def\numimages{#1}}
\begin{document}
\setnumimages{5}
\begin{figure}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\numimages}{
    \includegraphics{./assets/images/\x}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I modify your example to load images from a folder with arbirary names?

Comment: @random9 I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can build filenames out of macros. Can you give an example of what you mean by an "arbitrary" name?

Comment: Sure, let's say instead of `1.png`, `2.png`, ... I have something like `bla.png`, `foo.png`, ...

Comment: @random9 Instead of doing `\foreach \x in {1,...,\numimages}` you can give a literal list: `\foreach \x in {fee,fie,fo,fum,foo,bar}`.

Answer (score 0):

my working example :

```
% mwe.tex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}  
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\foreach \fig in {a,b,c}%
   {My picture: example-image-\fig \par%
   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-\fig}%
     \par%
     \vspace{2ex}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: Not really, but my code is a complete example executable without any adaptation. For a beginner, it can help. I put it in response because we cannot publish any code as a comment.